# VBA Loop through all files in folder and remove invalid characters

Tags: vba, for-loop, file-rename, invalid-characters

I found function that replace invalids characters in file name. I would like to use this for all files in one folder.

```
Function strLegalFileName(strFileNameIn As String) As String
Dim i As Integer

Const strIllegals = "\/|?*<>"":"
strLegalFileName = strFileNameIn
For i = 1 To Len(strIllegals)
    strLegalFileName = Replace(strLegalFileName, Mid$(strIllegals, i, 1), "_")
Next i
End Function
```

I don't know how to loop through all files and replace characters when include invalids.

Is it call function properly? by Debug.print command
There is my loop through all files, but I am not sure how to build it:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
  Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, FileName As Variant
  FileName = Dir("C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\testNazwa\")
   While (file <> "")
   Debug.Print strLegalFileName(strFileNameIn)
  file = Dir
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: The above only prints the replaced file names, but does not actually rename the file; is this correct? On a second thought, you would not have been able to create such files; because windows does not allow you to create files with invalid names. Could you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues with

- Your `Dir` loop
- Not actually renaming filenames that you have examined

The code below does this. Pls change `StrDir` to suit

But I note as these charcaters are ilegal the filenames should be invalid to begin with (hence my test looks at different characters)

*loop and rename code*

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim FName As Variant
Dim strNew As String
Dim strDir As String

strDir = "C:\temp\"
FName = Dir(strDir & "*.*")
Do While Len(FName) > 0
strNew = strLegalFileName(FName)
    If StrComp(strNew, FName) <> 0 Then Name (strDir & FName) As (strDir & strNew)
FName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

*string replace function*

```
Function strLegalFileName(ByVal FName) As String
Dim i As Integer

Const strIllegals = "P:"
strLegalFileName = FName
For i = 1 To Len(strIllegals)
    strLegalFileName = Replace(strLegalFileName, Mid$(strIllegals, i, 1), "_")
Next i
End Function
```

*Regexp Function alternative*

```
Function strLegalFileName(ByVal FName) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With objRegex
    .Pattern = "[\/\\\?\*\]\[\|:]"""
    .Global = True
    strLegalFileName = .Replace(FName, vbNullString)
End With

End Function
```